# Installing Hadoop in LinuxMint

Tags: linux, hadoop

I have started a course on Hadoop on  [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/the-ultimate-hands-on-hadoop-tame-your-big-data/learn/v4/overview). Now here the instructor is using windows OS and installs a virtual box and then runs a Horton Sandbox image for using Hadoop.
I am using LinuxMint and after doing some research on install hadoop on Linux I found[(click for ref)](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/24175/can-i-download-hortonworks-sandbox-and-install-in.html) out that we can install the VM on linux and download the Horton Sandbox image run it.

I also found another method which does not uses the VM [(click for ref)](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php). I am confused as to which is the best way for install hadoop.
Should I use the VM or the second method. Which is better for learning and development?

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can install the VM on linux

You can use a VM on any host OS... That's the point of a VM.

The last link is **only Hadoop**, where Hortonworks has much, much more like Spark, Hive, Hbase, Pig, etc. Things you'd need to additionally install and configure yourself otherwise

> Which is better for learning and development?

I would strongly suggest using a VM (or containers) overall

1) rather than messing up your local OS trying to get Hadoop working
2) The Hortonworks documentation has lots of tutorials that can really only be ran in the sandbox with the pre installed datasets